# Linux powershell command from terminal returns command not found

Tags: linux, powershell

I have a Linux box running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with Powershell on it, from the Linux terminal if I run:

```
sudo powershell (Invoke-Webrequest http://ipinfo.io/json | ConvertFrom-Json).ip
```

I get an error saying it is formatted incorrectly and expected a `')'` at the end. if I remove the `()` and just try to convert from JSON it throws a could not find the command `ConvertFrom-Json`.

That said if I actually go into powershell and run the original command it works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out need to wrap the command like this

```
sudo powershell '(Invoke-Webrequest http://ipinfo.io/json | ConvertFrom-Json).ip'
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used PowerShell on Linux (yet), but on Windows you'd need

```
powershell -Command { (Invoke-WebRequest http://ipinfo.io/json | ConvertFrom-JSON).ip }
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff I just tried and I still get the -Bash syntax error near unexpected token '('

Comment: OK, I don't speak bash, but my next suggestion would involve doing whatever bash requires to escape the parens - perhaps `\(` and `\)`? You may also need to escape the `|` as well.