# In what version of PowerShell was the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet made available?

Tags: .net, json, shell, web-services, powershell

To run this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44047852/262852) that uses the Invoke-WebRequest Cmdlet, I copied it into a one-line (plus echo) script as:

```
thufir >
thufir >
thufir > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8762
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


thufir >
thufir > type .\json_request.ps1

"start"

(Invoke-WebRequest http://ipinfo.io/json | ConvertFrom-JSON).ip

"done"
thufir >
thufir > .\json_request.ps1
start
The term 'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, functio
n, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a pa
th was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\604-083234\Desktop\json_request.ps1:4 char:19
+ (Invoke-WebRequest <<<<  http://ipinfo.io/json | ConvertFrom-JSON).ip
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-WebRequest:String) [], C
   ommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

done
thufir >
```

The Cmdlet does not exist in PowerShell V2. What version of PowerShell includes the Invoke-WebRequest Cmdlet?

Comment: It was available in v3

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` requires v3?

Comment: Just for future reference while you are exploring new cmdlets in powershell, the official MSDN documentation pages have a drop down that will show you the earliest version of powershell that includes a cmdlet. for instance, here is the link for this cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-3.0

Comment: Well, it requires v3+

Comment: @EBGreen that resolves problem for me.  thx.  and, thx for link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Invoke-WebRequest became available in PowerShell version 3